# How many versions of "Ico" are there?

Tags: version-differences, ico

As seen on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33744/1084) about Ico, there are different versions of this game with slightly different puzzles in some rooms. Many walkthroughs and youtube videos published show different solutions for the version I played in PS2 & PS3. What version was the first and how many are there? It is related to the region, may be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With respect to **gameplay**, there were two versions released for the PS2 ([an original version and a U.S. version](http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_bonuses_not_found_in_and_changes_from_the_U.S._version_of_Ico)), and one [remake for the PS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ico_&_Shadow_of_the_Colossus_Collection):

[image: U.S. and original version box art]

```
          U.S. Version               Original Version
```

[image: PS3 version box art]

```
          PS3 Remake
```

---

With respect to **language and region code**, there were [eight releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ico#toc), including one [reprint in Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ico) coinciding with the release of [Shadow of the Colossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Colossus):

> PlayStation 2
>
> ```
> NA September 24, 2001
> JP December 6, 2001
> EU March 22, 2002
> ```
>
> Re-Release
>
> ```
> EU February 17, 2006
> ```
>
> PlayStation 3
>
> ```
> JP September 22, 2011
> NA September 27, 2011
> AUS September 29, 2011
> EU September 28, 2011
> ```

Comment: Which gameplay version does the PS3 remake use?